# Centering a variable width div in a page

Tags: css

I am trying to centre a varying width div in the centre of a page. I'm creating a set of tiles which are set to float in a div so that as many fit in the page width as possible and automatically reconfigure if the page width is expanded or contracted.  This works fine.  But I would also like the div containing the tiles to be in the centre of the page.  Having looked at numerous solutions to centering in the forums, none of them seem to work for the scenario I am trying to create. The page is being displayed in an iframe and I wondered if that was the problem, but I tried its own page, with no change.

The basic div structure is shown below.  (Full PHP syntax omitted)

```
<div class="centre"> <!-- div containing the tiles -->
  Foreach (....) {   /* loop to create each tile */
    <div class="summary_tile" style="background-image: image-url"> <!-- div for each tile -->
      <div style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);"> <!-- background to write text over images within each tile -->
      </div>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is shown below.  I have tried various versions (show as centreN in the CSS below) of the class centre and the results are shown in the comments.

```
div.summary_tile
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

div.centre /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window width but not centered */
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.centre1 /* reduces display to 2 tiles wide, but still not centered - remains fixed when window width reduced - not what I want anyway, but just tried the fixed width to see if it worked */
{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.centre2 /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window     width but not centered */
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align; center;
}

div.centre3 /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window width but not centered */
{
  display: flex;
  align-items; center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align; center;
}

div.centre4 /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window     width but not centered */
{
  display: table;
  align-items; center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align; center;
}

div.centre5 /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window     width but not centered */
{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align; center;
}

div.centre6 /* tiles fill width of window - number of tiles in row varies according to window     width but not centered */
{
  text-align; center;
}
```

I have also tried an outer containing div with each of the centre class options and no class on the div containing the tiles or with various of the classes, but that doesn't seem to work.  Am I trying to do the impossible or just not hit on the correct combination of CSS statements and divs yet?

Comment: try adding text-align; center; in the div.centre or in div.summary_tile

Comment: That had been one of my first options.  I've tried it again just in case I had too many interactions, but no luck.